# How to display confirm message on GridView Image button

Tags: asp.net

I have the following button on GridView and I want to display a message box to the user for confirming whether he is sure or not for buying the item.(I'm familiar with OnClientClick= return confirm('xxxxx'); ) but on Grid View it is different I can't use this method though.

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="buynow" ImageUrl="~/images/buy.png" HeaderText="BUY" ButtonType="Image"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use itemtemplate field in column node in gridview markup

eg.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Save">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to save?')" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```